# Efficient conversion of a ByteArray object into a hexadecimal string

Tags: conversion

What is the best way to convert `ByteArray` objects into hexadecimal string representation? Although the following works, I find it questionably awkward (and likely not very efficient):

```
ByteArray[{9, 182, 236, 38, 171, 0, 236, 56}] // 
 StringJoin@IntegerString[Normal@#, 16, 2] &
```

> "09b6ec26ab00ec38"

I contrast this complication with `BaseEncode` which directly converts `ByteArray`s to Base64 encoding.

(**EDIT**: Sure, considering the shortness of the solution one might consider this question a sort of a thinly veiled feature request! Still, I'm curious of any better alternatives.)